# Array Exchange and Reversing problem on Code Wars

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
# before
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
other_list = [1, 2, 3]

exchange_with(my_list, other_list)

# after
my_list == [3, 2, 1]
other_list == ['c', 'b', 'a']
```

So I just finished solving the problem and I thought i had solved it with my solution below which was

```
def exchange_with(a, b):

    a , b = b , a

    print(a[::-1])
    print("\n")
    print(b[::-1])
```

and the solution comes out right but when I submit it it says

```
Test Results:
 Log (MY RESULTS)
['c', 'b', 'a']
['7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1']
====================================================

['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7'] should equal ['c', 'b', 'a']
['a', 'b', 'c'] should equal ['7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1']
```

I am very confused on what I did wrong I swapped each list and reversed it but it won't let me submit my solution

Comment: Does the Code Wars problem _specifically_ ask you to print the result, or create an object with the result? Because the reversal of the lists is within the `print` call in what you've shown here

Comment: It just says "It's time for some array exchange! The objective is simple: exchange the elements of two arrays in-place in a way that their new content is also reversed."

Comment: Which you only half did, as far as their arbitrary solution parser is concerned

Comment: So you haven't done that. You've only exchanged names. You should be able to print those lists without the `[::-1]` and get the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from what I understand here:

```
# before
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
other_list = [1, 2, 3]

exchange_with(my_list, other_list)

# after
my_list == [3, 2, 1]
other_list == ['c', 'b', 'a']
```

you have to mutate the lists and the 'Test results' will evaluate your mutation, in which case you can try:

```
def exchange_with(my_list, other_list):
    my_list[:], other_list[:] = other_list[::-1], my_list[::-1]
```

how it works (should not be used in your solution):

```
my_list = ['c', 'b', 'a']
other_list = ['7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1']
exchange_with(my_list, other_list)
print(my_list)
print(other_list)
```

output:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Comment: Your answered work for the def exchange_with(my_list,other_list)? I am just confused because I did exactly the same thing with my solution but it didn't go through lol

Comment: Oh okay gotcha thank you so much kedarrac appreciate it!